# How to set AWS apigw authorization as aleady created custom authorizer using terraform

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create API GW and integration using terraform. I dont know how to link

custom authorizer to Authorization via terraform.

1. Now : [image]
2. Expectation : [image]
   [image]

I tried  "x-amazon-apigateway-authtype" : "custom" and multiple aws docs. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

In addition to having an `aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer` resource, you also have to configure the authorizer on the `aws_apigatewayv2_route` resource.

For example:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "connect_route" {
  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api.apigw.id
  route_key = "$connect"
  target    = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.lambda-integration.id}"
  authorization_type = "CUSTOM"
  authorizer_id = aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer.authorizer.id
}
```

`aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer` adds the authorizer to the API Gateway, and `aws_apigatewayv2_route` sets it as the active authorizer for the route you set up.